# How can I copy a DataTable while converting data types?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datatable

I have a DataTable populated with the following columns, `UPC`, `NUMBER`, `DESCRIPTION`, `BRAND`, `UOM`, `GROUP`, `TOTAL_DOLLARS`, `TOTAL_UNITS`, and `DATE`.  They are all of type `String` except for `Date`, which is already in DateTime format.

I would like to either--

1. (Ideally) write this DataTable to a SQL Server Database Table
2. Copy this DataTable to another DataTable

--while converting all of the values in the `TOTAL_DOLLARS` column to `Decimal` and all of the values in the `TOTAL_UNITS` column to `Int32`.  Note that there are no null values, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values can be converteted without additional chances:

```
Select UPC, NUMBER, DESCRIPTION, BRAND, UOM, [GROUP], Cast(TOTAL_DOLLARS as Decimal(38,17)) as TOTAL_DOLLARS, Cast(TOTAL_UNITS as int) as TOTAL_UNITS, DATE
Into NewTable
From OldTable
```